# Ambiguous definition of `integer conversion rank`

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, coercion

In `6.3 Conversions`, the *integer conversion rank* for signed integer types is defined as proportional with the *precision*.

> The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision. C11 §6.3.1.1 1

After that, it says,

> The rank of `long long int` shall be greater than the rank of `long int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `int`, which shall be greater than the rank of `short int`, which shall be greater than ... etc

So, this is ambiguous.  Because the precision of `int` can be equal either to the precision of `long` or equal to the precision of `short`, depending on the implementation of int.

The precision of `int` may either be that one of `long` or `short` (definition in `<limits.h>`). On the other hand it says that rank(`int`) < rank (`short`), even if in `<limits.h>` they may be the same.

Where is the ambiguity in all this stuff?

Comment: There's no ambiguity. That "the rank of any signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision" does not imply that the signed integer types with the same precision need have the same rank.

Comment: rank / range. rank is used for conversions and integer types are strictly ordered by rank, but their range (precision if you want) are weakly ordered. range of long may equals range of ints, but rank of long is greater than rank of int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally `long long > long > int > short` when it comes to precision. Even if that's not the case and they're all the same precision this still means that the rank is `long long > long > int > short`. The second passage explicitly states that.

`short` won't ever have a higher rank than `long` for example. Even if they're the same precision on the platform.

In other words, the precision of the data type can differ from platform to platform (it could be `long long > long > int > short` but could also be `long long == long == int == short`), the *rank* of these types is always the same, as specified by the standard : `long long > long > int > short`.

There is no ambiguity because the first passage:

> The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of
>   any signed integer type with less precision..

Only says that a type with a higher precision than the other type *must* have a higher rank than the other type.

Then the second passage:

> The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int,
>   which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater
>   than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than ... etc

Is for cases where the platform has 2 different types with equal precision, in this case the standard says that the rank *is always* : `long long > long > int > short`.

Precision of a type is platform dependent (with the only exception that a type of a higher rank as specified in the standard must have equal or bigger precision than the type with a lower rank).
rank of a type is specified by the standard and thus platform independent.

Comment: Then why the definition of rank is ambiguous ?

Comment: Where is it ambiguous? Even if the precisions are all the same the first quote might hold.

Comment: Where is it ambigious?

Comment: It says the precision of INT may either be that one of LONG or SHORT (definition in limits.h).   On the other hand it says that rank(INT) < rank (SHORT), even if in limits.h they may be the same.

Comment: @alinsoar Yes, the precision might be different on different platforms (precision being equal or higher), but the rank is _always the same_.

Comment: I think the question is clearly formulated, and I ask about the ambiguity, sorry -- you did not answer the same question.

Comment: @alinsoar I edited my answer, I don't see how the passage confuses you.

Comment: What happens when precision(LONG)=precision(INT)? -- is the RANK(LONG) still greater RANK(INT) even if they are the same  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123446/discussion-between-gill-bates-and-alinsoar).

Answer (score 1):

There is no ambiguity.

The two passages you quote:

> The rank of a signed integer type shall be greater than the rank of any signed integer type with less precision..

and

> The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than ... etc

... do not contradict each other. Let us assign a numeric rank to each of `long int`, `int` and `short int`. Suppose the rank of `long int` is 2, the rank of `int` is 1 and the rank of  `short int` is 0. Now, regardless of whether `int` has the same precision as `short int` or `long int` or somewhere in between, both the above statements are satisfied. There is no contradiction and no ambiguity.

I think you are incorrectly interpreting the first statement as saying that signed integer types with the same precision must have the same rank, however, it does not say this. It merely requires that *if* two signed integer types have different precision, the one with greater precision has higher rank than the other. I also suspect that by "ambiguous" you mean "self-contradictory" (which, again, it is not).

Comment: I clarified the ambiguity in chat with Gill Bates and I will accept his answer after he updates.

Answer (score 0):

> So, this is ambiguous. Because the precision of int can be equal either to the precision of long or equal to the precision of short, depending on the implementation of int.

It may be difficult to follow, but it is not ambiguous.  There is no conflict between the two provisions you quoted because nowhere do they say that the integer conversion rank of two different types with the same precision must be equal.

In practice, the precision-based requirement is most applicable to extended integer types; for the standard integer types it is redundant with the explicitly-given ordering requirement.

> Where is the ambiguity in all this stuff ?

The standards committee works hard to avoid ambiguity in the specification.  Although it has not been completely successful, it has done a pretty good job in that regard.  There's no ambiguity involving the provisions you ask about.

Comment: I clarified the ambiguity in chat with Gill Bates and I will accept his answer after he updates.

Answer (score 0):

**Precision**

> Because the precision of `int` can be equal either to the precision of `long` or equal to the precision of `short`, depending on the implementation of `int`.  ... The precision of `int` may either be that one of `long` or `short`

This is true, but incomplete.  The precision of `int` can be instead be *unequal  to both* `short` and `long`.  In that case, it will be between `short` and `int`.

The following is required by the C spec.  Precision may or may not be the same (ties) between the types.

```
precision(short) <= precision(int) <= precision(long)
```

---

**Rank**

> On the other hand it says that rank(int) < rank (short), even if in  they may be the same.

When operations involve different types, the type of lower rank operand is converted to the type of the higher ranking operand.  The is independent of precision.  With `short`, `int`, `long`, there are no *ties* concerning *rank*.    The difference in *rank* is true even if all 3 types had the same precision.

```
rank(short) < rank(int) < rank(long)
```

Comment: The real problem here was why they added the concept of rank in order to define the coercions as time as the concept of precision would have done the job.

Comment: @alinsoar With 2 types, certainly when precision is greater/lesser, rank is greater/lesser.  So the usefulness of _rank_ comes in when 2 types have the same precision yet different types.  32-bit `int/long` is a typical example.  I see the idea of _rank_ reduces ambiguity as then `int_a op long_b` can _only_ have **1** compliant type result of `long`.  I see this useful with `_Generic()` but not much else yet.  Will ponder.